# Updating Polymorphic Associations in Rails on change in model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have three classes Picture, Employee and Product defined this way

```
Class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

I want to change the Model name of Picture to Image. What all do I need to update regarding the polymorphic associations?

Answer (score 2):

First rename the filename: from `picture.rb` to `image.rb`, the class name: from `Picture` to `Image` and the associations: from `has_many :pictures` to `has_many :images`.

Then create a migration that changes your pictures table, like this:

```
class RenamePicturesToImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :pictures, :images
  end
end
```

Finally run `rake db:migrate`.